# How to update Kubernetes Cluster to the latest version available?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I began to try Google Container Engine recently. I would you like to upgrade the Kubernetes Cluster to the latest version available, if possible without downtime. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best answer we currently have is to create a new cluster and move your resources over, then delete the old one.

We are very actively working on making cluster upgrades reliable (both [nodes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/6079) and the [master](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/6075)), but upgrades are unlikely to work for the majority of currently existing clusters.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRobinson. I will closely monitor through Kubernetes repository.

Answer (score 2):

We now have a checked-in upgrade tool for master and nodes: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/gce/upgrade.sh