# How to create multiple kubernetes cluster with curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am running a 1.0.3 kubernetes cluster in AWS and used curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash to install it.

I would like to have another cluster to allow me to upgrade to a newer kubernetes version as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29503904/3045).

When I try to install another cluster it gives an error.

```
A client error (InvalidIPAddress.InUse) occurred when calling the RunInstances operation: Address 172.20.0.9 is in use.
```

What's the process to create another cluster using the installation scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul,
Check out the following file:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/aws/config-default.sh
The second time, the defaults would need to be updated.

If your goal is to simply upgrade the Kubernetes components, have you tried https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/kube-push.sh ?